# Can InvokeMethod be used as optional parameters?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have  base class `A` in a project

There are many subclasses that inherits from `A`

```
public class A
{
    public void Process(string myString1, int myInt1   )
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();
            type.InvokeMember("ImAChildMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
                                                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                null, 
                                                this, 
                                                new object[] { myString1, myInt1  });
        }
}
```

Subclass :

```
public class B:A
{
   private void ImAChildMethod(string myString, int myInt )
    {
     Console.WriteLine (myInt + ","+myString);
    }
}
```

So when I Exeucte :

`new B().Process("aaa",15);` I get

> 15,aaa

**Great**.

Days have passed and now we need to send — not:

`new object[] { myString1, myInt1  }`

but

`new object[] { myString1, myInt1 , MyDateTime }`

*(however , not all subclasses uses this datetime parameter)*

Ok so we changed (at the specific places) from :

```
 private void ImAChildMethod(string myString, int myInt )
```

to

```
 private void ImAChildMethod(string myString, int myInt ,DateTime myDateTime )
```

So where is the problem ?

It caused exception in places that we did not change.

**Question**

I don't want to go through all sub classes and add this parameter of datetime. ( not all subclasses uses this parameter)

Is there a way to "pre-recognize" that `ImAChildMethod` does / doesn't have `,DateTime myDateTime` and if it has : use it , and if it doesn't - ignore the new parameter ?

Nb

I'm pretty sure that I'll have to go through subclasses and add optional parameter...but I might be wrong ?

Comment: any reason why ImAChildMethod is not abstract in A?

Comment: @vc74 "ImAChildMethod" is a string which is being sent from the client  , so a client can run the "x" method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional parameters are really a compile-time feature - the CLR and framework have very little to do with them, other than to make the information *available* via reflection.

So while you can detect the fact that a parameter is optional (with [`ParameterInfo.IsOptional`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isoptional(v=vs.110).aspx)) and get the default value (with [`ParameterInfo.DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)) you need to do that explicitly - `InvokeMember` doesn't do it for you.

You may want to write a helper method which is effectively like `InvokeMember`, but handles optional parameters... just bear in mind that if you only accept a *name*, you'll get into the awkward business of overload resolution. You might want to restrict it to only work with names with a single overload, just for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the optional parameter to `Process` method and then check if the child method has two or three parameters, then call it accordingly:

```
public void Process(string myString1, int myInt1, DateTime date = default(DateTime))
{
     Type type = this.GetType();
     var flags =  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
     var method = type.GetMethod("ImAChildMethod", flags);
     if(method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
     {
         type.InvokeMember("ImAChildMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
                                           | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                           | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                                           null, 
                                           this, 
                                           new object[] { myString1, myInt1  });
     } 
     else
     {
         type.InvokeMember("ImAChildMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
                                           | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                           | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                                           null, 
                                           this, 
                                           new object[] { myString1, myInt1,vdate  });
     }
}
```